# Docker compose not using external named volume on Mac

Tags: macos, docker-compose

Though I mount data on external volume, upon `docker-compose down` I am losing my data. I am using docker-compose version `1.14.0, build c7bdf9e` and docker version `17.06.1-ce, build 874a737`

```
# docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/postgres/data
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
     - .:/myapp
    ports:
     - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
     - db

volumes:
  data:
    external: true
```

Comment: Can you try the latest 1.15.0 version?

Comment: @TarunLalwani I think 1.14 is the latest version for docker compose on MAC. When I am trying to update it shows that I have the latest version only.

Comment: That is not true. I just did `pip install docker-compose` and `docker-compose -v` gives me `docker-compose version 1.16.0, build ea60ca1`